# Response data issue in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Iam new to Jmeter, and working on my application "uat.centramed.co/centramedAnalytics" . I have record the script for Login and a Report transactions, when i run the script the response for login is correct but the same login response is shown for Report.  I have checked the Network traffic using Firebug in browser and the same was recorded in Jmeter. Please suggest me how to resolve the issue.

The application was developed in Java using Html5.

Comment: If it's your application, as you said, then probably you know how the request should look like, so try to insert correct request manually - in the proper place in your thread group add -> sampler -> HTTP request and configure it the way you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Faflok. I have checked the response by changing the Implementaion to Java and disabling Keep Alive options but still iam not getting the expected response. Both Login and Report showing the same response.

Answer (score 0):

You login probably create cookie of JSESSIONID which is expected in report

Just add HTTP Cookie Manager before your login and it'll save and send it in report request.